# Automatically input in a program which needs input and enter of the user to simplify debug process

Tags: c, bash, makefile, io, user-input

Is it possible to automatically generate input for a program that needs input from the user, for example with a bashscript or a makefile?

As an example, let's say I have a program which tells the user if the character he entered is a number or not. To test/debug it I have to

1. compile  (command `gcc the_program.c`
2. run the program (command `./a.out`)
3. input the character (example: `2`) and press enter.

after this I will get the ouput `e is a not a number`

Is there a way to automate the process 1. 2. and 3. in one single command in order to speed up the test/debug process?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int c;
  c = getchar();
  if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
  {
    printf("%c is a number\n", c);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%c is not a number\n", c);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `gcc the_program.c; echo "2" | ./a.out`?

Comment: [make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software))